# node to traverse cannot be null hibernate update

Tags: java, hibernate

hi i am coming to the point directly 
below is my query while i am try to execute the query i am getting this exception 
node to traverse cannot be null.

```
 @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = query = session.createQuery("UPDATE User set isLocked =:locked, wrongAttempt=:attempt  where userId in(:list)");
query.executeUpdate();
```

while i am writting the query with

```
Query query= session.createSQLQuery("update user where is_locked=:locked,wrong_attempt=:attempt where user_id in(:list)") 
query.executeUpdate();
```

working fine.
can you please any body do let me know why i am getting this exception in first case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing it this way, it is so much error prone. Do in this fashion

```
public void yourUpdateMethod(){
User user = (User)session.get(User.class,userId);
if(!(user==null)){
 user.setNoLock(true);
// Above line is just an example, set whatever you want to, ideally this should be done in Service layer, but okay for now
    session.merge(user);
    session.flush();
  }
}
```

This way you wont have errors, and no need to use SQL queries. Also, if Hibernate is complaining that it cannot update a Null entity, means the user was not found, that's exactly why I am checking if user is not null.

Comment: thanks for your reply. here i am getting the list of userId.

Comment: i don't understand your null checking here i am trying to remove a lock of the user  in data base table base on his id so what is the need of this.

Comment: Yes, but you should also check if the user is there or not. It is a good practice. Also, the point of using Hibernate is, you minimize the dependency of using SQL queries in your code and use Java code, which is exactly what I am doing.